# On Ubuntu 22.04, he internet is extremely slow and times out

Tags: networking, wireless, internet

My Asus Vivobook 17 acts like it's connected to the internet, but it's extremely slow, so slow that it times out. Not a single webpage will load. I've ran network diagnostics and everything says its working and connected to the internet, when it's clearly not.
I took it to a computer repair shop and they said it was merely a software issue and nothing to do with hardware, and said I likely turned something on or off accidentally.

Is there a way I could view a log of all of the commands I ran to figure out what I turned on or off?

Is there some way I could restore my network settings to defaults?

My network card is Intel Wi-Fi 6 AX201

I just recently switched to Ubuntu from Windows 10 and I don't have a clue what's going wrong.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.